# Sampling from an integrated tail distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling

Let $Y$ be a positive random variable with density $g$ and cdf $G$. Let $c := \mathbb E Y$. Define a random variable $X$ with density $f(x):= \frac1{c}\mathbb P(Y > x)$. Not a surprise that this defines a density. However, given an algorithm to sample from $X$ (or from $Y$) is there a good way to sample from $Y$ (or $X$, resp.)?

References and ideas are welcome as much as answers!

Comment: Welcome to CV, Ben.  Is the sampling algorithm allowed to compute $g,$ $G,$ or $f,$ or must it utilize only the samples given to it?

Comment: @whuber, ideally not using any of them, only the samples.

Answer (score 1):

For the reverse direction (sampling X when given a sampler for Y), I have a partial answer for this:

(1) Sample Y.
(2) Sample N from Poisson(Y). (Although any nonnegative discrete distribution that has mean Y will work as well).
(3) Sample X uniformly in [0,Y) a total of N times.

As you notice, the amount of samples the algorithm provides per run is variable. That is because the algorithm is more like a density approximator rather than a true sampler. Individual samples are not i.i.d.; however, the set of all samples obtained from this algorithm will converge to the true distribution of X. A single sampler can be made out of this framework by uniformly selecting a sample among those already collected after collecting a sufficient amount of samples.

The idea behind this algorithm is that step (2) provides a size biasing on Y by giving higher values of Y more samples. In effect, it samples a distribution with density $\frac{t}{c}g(t)$ in a somewhat messy way. Via conditioning on the size biased Y, the density of X would be $\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{t}{c}g(t)  \frac{1}{t} dt = \frac{1}{c} \mathbb{P}(Y > x)$ as desired.